# How I can restore/reset the /etc/fstab on amazon AWS EC-2 ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: fstab, swap, amazon-ec2

In an amazon EC-2 instance I accidentally overwrote the `/etc/fstab` while I was adding a setting fro swapfile:

```
echo "/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0" | sudo tee /etc/fstab
```

But I have **not** rebooted the machin yet. How I can restore it whilst keeping the swap settings on it?

The current contents of `/etc/fstab` only contains:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0
```

The only volume that I have is the one generated upon EC-2 creation.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 2.04 instances running on Amazon EC-2 using a single volume you can use the following:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro   0 1
LABEL=UEFI  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0 1

/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0
```

Somehow Amazon has configured to use default labels for volume mounts. Keep in mind that In my case I only use a single volume that has been generated upon **instance creation** in your case you may need to place extra settings as well.